# サンプルデータにセットするための、一定の長さのランダムな文字列を生成するための簡単な方法

Tags: ruby

Railsで開発をしているさいに、バリテーションテストであったり、表示テストを行いたいさいに、任意の長さを持つランダムな文字列を作成して、それを使いたいとします。現在、以下のような汚いワンライナーを利用して、それを実現しています:

```
  random_string = ->(n){ ->{ (0..n).map{ ->{ ["a", "あ"].sample }.call() }}.call().join }

  random_string.call(10)
  # => "aあaaaaあaああa"

  random_string.call(20)
  # => "あaaaaaaaaaあaaああaあaaああ"

  random_string.call(30)
  # => "ああaあaaaあああああaあaaaああああああaaaあaあaあ"
```

当然のことながら、このようなワンライナーは書く分にも読む分にもあまり綺麗ではありませんし、もう少しいい方法があるのではないかと思いました。

ちなみに、意図しているのは以下の通りです:

- このメソッドは `each`などで利用することを意図しています。例としては `User.all.each { |u| u.name = random_string.call(30) }`という感じで。
- 生成する文字列に使用する文字列は指定できるほうが望ましい。例えば、上の例なら、サンプルの文字列に`あ`と`a`だけを利用したい
- 呼び出されるたびに違う文字列を生成したい(何度呼んでも同じ文字列だと困る)
- 生成する文字列を引数などを使って指定できると嬉しい

以上、いい方法があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[faker](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker) ライブラリの、[Faker::Base](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/Faker/Base) と [Faker::Lorem](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/Faker/Lorem) が目的にあっていそうです。
導入は `gem install faker`。`require 'faker'`でインポート。

#### ランダム文字列の生成

```rb
# ランダムな16個の文字
Faker::Lorem.characters(16)
=> "soqw6mqnla295y72"

# 32文字の`a`と`あ`からなる文字列
Faker::Base.regexify("[aあ]{32}")
=> "aあaaあaあaあああaaああaああaあああああaあaaあaああ"
```

#### 名前の生成

```rb
# それらしい名前を生成
Faker::Name.name
=> "Robbie Monahan"

# 8人分名前作ってループ
(0..8).map{ Faker::Name.name }.each{|n| p n}
"Ewell Miller"
"Anita Kreiger"
"Abe Runolfsdottir"
"Nikita Dietrich"
"Paige Heathcote"
"Gracie Keebler"
"Coleman Kuphal"
"Ms. Darius Effertz"
"Misael Lockman"
```

#### 数値の生成

```rb
# 下４桁電話サンプリング (dial_telephone というメソッドは自分で作ること)
(0..100).map{Faker::Base.numerify "0120-3218-####"}.each{|n| dial_telephone n}
```

#### 段落の生成

自分が Website を作る際は、ランダムの文字の塊ではダメなので、以下のようにすると思います。

```rb
# 3つの文からなる段落を作成
Faker::Lorem.paragraph(sentence_count = 3)
=> "Porro vero qui et iste amet. Totam magni quidem nisi necessitatibus voluptatum modi. Accusamus temporibus sed rerum incidunt esse excepturi rerum. Sit adipisci rerum qui corporis. Fuga aliquam dolorem in."
```

Answer (score 3):

綺麗か汚いかは個人の感覚なのですけど、私は、

```
random_string = ->(n){ ->{ (0..n).map{ ->{ ["a", "あ"].sample }.call() }}.call().join }
```

よりは

```
random_string = ->(n){ n.times.map{["a", "あ"].sample}.join }
```

の方が読みやすいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

無理にラムダを使わず、普通にメソッドを定義したほうが柔軟性と可読性が高くなるかなーと思います。
というわけで、こんなメソッドを考えてみました。

```
LENGTH_MIN_MAX = 5..20
ALPHABETS = [*'A'..'Z', *'a'..'z']
def random_string(length: Random.rand(LENGTH_MIN_MAX), chars: ALPHABETS)
  length.times.map { chars.sample }.join
end

random_string
=> "CjeRHhRUDKbgzlsrDYOE"

random_string
=> "gxbKbtni"

random_string length: 30
=> "fmrvimfqopyiymbdapwmharpkizuft"

random_string chars: %w(A x p)
=> "ApAxxAxxpAAxppxppAxp"

random_string length: 15, chars: %w(Z d f)
=> "ZddZZdZddffffdZ"
```

ただ、Hiroshi Yamamotoさんも書いているように、Faker gemを活用するほうが目的に合っている気がしますね。

Answer (score 1):

これは それなりに汎用的な問題なので、いろいろなアイデアがあるようです。
参考情報として、"random string ruby" で google 検索した結果からいつくかを抜粋して紹介します。

- Generate Random String in Ruby http://yankist.com/blog/2012/11/28/generate-random-string-in-ruby/
- シンプルにRubyっぽく、ランダムな文字列生成 http://qiita.com/diaphragm/items/50b2703c3cd4ba8490a9
- How best to generate a random string in Ruby http://www.acnenomor.com/2105018p1/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby